# How to quickly "uninterested" a youtube video?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm new to JS/_monkeyscripts, aiming to write a little script that helps me disinterests youtube videos quickly.

Here is the code block for the "Not Interested" button, given in youtube's main page.

```
<ytd-menu-service-item-renderer class="style-scope ytd-menu-popup-renderer" role="menuitem" use-icons="" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false"><!--css-build:shady-->
    
    <paper-item class="style-scope ytd-menu-service-item-renderer" role="option" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false"><!--css-build:shady-->
    
    
      <yt-icon class="style-scope ytd-menu-service-item-renderer"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" class="style-scope yt-icon" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="style-scope yt-icon">
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" class="style-scope yt-icon"></path>
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8 0-1.85.63-3.55 1.69-4.9L16.9 18.31C15.55 19.37 13.85 20 12 20zm6.31-3.1L7.1 5.69C8.45 4.63 10.15 4 12 4c4.42 0 8 3.58 8 8 0 1.85-.63 3.55-1.69 4.9z" class="style-scope yt-icon"></path>
      </g></svg><!--css-build:shady-->

</yt-icon>
      <yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-menu-service-item-renderer">Not interested</yt-formatted-string>
    
</paper-item>
  </ytd-menu-service-item-renderer>
```

How to proceed to disinterest videos by clicking through the thumbnails?

Comment: Have you tried anything? [Automating clicks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) with basic [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) should be quite simple.

Comment: Hmm.. being pretty new to this I spent hours to come to this point. Thanks so much for pointing out them. I will take a look!

Comment: @Student if you spent hours, you can add the code that you made and doesn't work to your question and we can help you find the problem

Comment: This is not exactly trivial, see `onClick` in [my userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/396936-yt-not-interested-in-one-click/code) for this purpose.